# Working out Tornado exception

Tags: python, tornado

Hi I have the following code:

```
    httpClient=AsyncHTTPClient()
    try:
       response=yield httpClient.fetch("http://ww.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-000")

    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

I am intentionally fetching an invalid URL to work out how to handle errors. With the above I get:

```
[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

However I'm trying to work out what exception class this is so I did the following:

```
    httpClient=AsyncHTTPClient()
    try:
       response=yield httpClient.fetch("http://ww.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-000")

    except Exception as e:
       print(type(e))
```

And I get:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado-4.1-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/tornado/gen.py", line 810, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*sys.exc_info())
  File "messages.py", line 230, in on_message
    print(type(e))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Firstly I don't understand why the type(e) in this code isn't working to show me what type of Exception class this is?

And secondly the tornado documentation states that a HTTPError is thrown however it doesn't look like this covers all Exception that can be thrown.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have another variable named `type` that is shadowing the built-in function `type`?

The docs state that `HTTPError` is raised when the server returns a non-200 response code, but if we don't make it that far then other exceptions may be raised. This one is a `socket.gaierror`, but there is no limit on what may be raised so you must use `except Exception` to catch everything.

Comment: Ben thanks for that. I'm feeling like a bit of an idiot now... I was using a variable called type :S and going crazy as to why this wasn't working...